# How to make field readonly based on group and status?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to make field `readonly` based on group, and status. Like I have two groups:

1. Manager Group
2. User Group

If I give **User Group** to **any user** and then change **Status** to **Done**, then field will be `readonly` for this user.

Hope I was able to make it clear to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Create a functional field of type boolean. If the logged in user is under user group and state is done, then return true. Then in the view, specify `attrs="{'readonly':[('boolean_field_name','=',True)]}"`

OR

First create your form view. Then inherit the view also specify the groups. for example in sale order form view, i want to make the customer reference field readonly for group user when state is not in draft or sent.

```xml
<record id="view_order_form_cust_ref_readonly" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form.readonly.cust</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_user') ])]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name='client_order_ref'" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly':[('state','not in',['draft','sent'])]}</attribute>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: tanks friends for help

Comment: Is this method safe? Can this still be injected by JSON direct call?

Comment: sorry.i didnt get you

Comment: @OmaL The first solution worked, but the second didn't work. Thankyou

Comment: @PravithaV the second should work. its the best solution than the first one

Comment: First solution worked for me. Second looks logical but didn't work in  my case.

Comment: Really nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

you can apply access rule on field level in OpenERP, like in py

```
'name': fields.char('Name', size=128, required=True, select=True,
 read=['base.group_user'] ),
```

And for status in xml:

```
<field name="name " attrs="{'readonly': [('state','=','done')]}"/>
```

Comment: hi heroic, you code work at when state done it make readonly form wheather user belongs or not to group. I want group and state both condition to mathc

Comment: Try this :<field name="name" attrs="{'readonly':[('groups_id.category_id.name','=','User Group'),('state','=','done')]}"/>

Answer (score 3):

There is another sweet way to achieve this. Create one functional field and in that check for group assigned to that user and do not store that field. In View use that field in attrs.

Let say in product you don't want to allow any user to modify **Internal Reference** if user does not belongs to **Product Modify** group.

Create one group.

```
<data noupdate="1" >
    <record model="res.groups" id="group_product_modify">
        <field name="name">Product Modify</field>
        <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/> 
    </record>
</data>
```

**Python file**

```
class product_template(models.Model):
    _inherit="product.template"

    @api.one
    def set_access_for_product(self):
        self.able_to_modify_product = self.env['res.users'].has_group('product_extended_ecom_ept.group_product_modify')

    able_to_modify_product = fields.Boolean(compute=set_access_for_product, string='Is user able to modify product?')
```

**XMl** file should be looking like,

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_template_update_internal_code_ept">
            <field name="name">Product Template extension</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="50" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="default_code" position="before">
                    <field name="able_to_modify_product" invisible="1" />
                </field>
                <field name="default_code" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly' : [('able_to_modify_product','=',False)]}</attribute>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using Odoo web client(GUI) instead of code then there is a bit unorthodox way to do it.
Just make a copy of the field which will contain same value as the original one(giving original field name in `Related Field` under `Advanced Properties`) and mark it as read-only.

[image]
Then you can hide original field from the users which cannot edit that field and hide the copy field from those who can edit by using groups attribute.

[image]