# OpenERP (XML) - hide view depending on access rights group

Tags: xml, view, hide, odoo

I need to hide view that I create for users that do not have specific access rights group. I know I can use `groups` attribute for every field that I add in my view, so those users would not see it. But it is quite redundant as I need to hide every field in that view. So maybe there is some way that I can just hide whole view? In this example it hides for every field, because group is added for those fields.

```
   <record id="view_partner_additional_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.patient.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="priority">2</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <label for="is_company" string="Is a Company?" position="after">
                <field name="is_something"                          
                    attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=',True)]}" 
                    groups="some_grp"/>             
                <field name="is_something2" 
                    attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=',False)]}" 
                    groups="some_grp"/>                 
           </label>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Is it possible to somehow wrap whole view and define it that it will be invisible to user that does not have 'some_grp' access rights group? What I mean is that I would need to add groups attribute once, not for every field. I tried wrapping everything with `div` and then adding `groups` attribute there, but I got error, because you can't wrap it everything like that.

Comment: there is a groups_id field on model ir.ui.view. did you try that out? edit: you can hide whole menus with groups_id field in menuitems, too.

Comment: @CZoellner I'm trying to hide view, not menu. Or I don't understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: every view has the field groups_id. help of this field says: empty = every user can see this view; entries: only registered groups should see the view. but i tested it and it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your form view. Then inherit the view also specify the groups. for example in sale order form view, i want to make the customer reference field readonly for group user when state is not in draft or sent.

```
<record id="view_order_form_cust_ref_readonly" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form.readonly.cust</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_user') ])]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name='client_order_ref'" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly':[('state','not in',['draft','sent'])]}</attribute>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

In your case,first create a view which is common for all users. Then inherit the view with groups and add the fields that need to be visible for the group specified.

reference [How to make field readonly based on group and status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912997/how-to-make-field-readonly-based-on-group-and-status/19144004#19144004)

Comment: I'm wondering why there's no way to specify a separate view for each group. Why do I have to inherit?

Comment: if you want you can create seperate views. but you have to create seperate actions also and assign each views to it for its correct working