# How to Hide Filters in Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14

How can I hide a filter in Odoo, I know I can use a record rule but in my case I can't.
This is not working.

***Please Note: This is not the filter I want to hide.***

```
<filter name="today" **invisible="1"** string="Today's Investigation" domain="[('date','&gt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(0,0,0))), ('date','&lt;=', datetime.datetime.combine(context_today(), datetime.time(23,59,59)))]"/>
```

Comment: According to your comment below “ What i want is to make a filter of my own then hide it so that users cann't remove it  ” your question is really badly written.

Answer (score 0):

The record rule is the best solution as far as i know an example of record rule on filter is

```
            <field name="name">ir.filters.own.rule.delete</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_ir_filters"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', user.id)]</field>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
            <field name="perm_read" eval="False"/>
            <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
            <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
        </record>
```

Comment: I did try all this first but it couldn't help, this is why i resolated to hiding filters in odoo

Comment: It does work for own rules so maybe you are having problems with writing record rules

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution [How to make field readonly based on group and status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912997/how-to-make-field-readonly-based-on-group-and-status/19144004#19144004) apply similar changes to your search view. I believe you need to show the filter to specific groups only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand utility of hide a filter. But if you want remove it, you can inherit the xml search view with the filter and xpath + replace the filter:

```
<xpath expr="//filter[@name='today']" position="replace">
</xpath>
```

The most importante in this code is `position="replace"`.

Comment: Thank you @jo541 but that is not what i want. What i want is to make a filter of my own then hide it so that users cann't remove it

Comment: I suppose it's to open a view with default filter ?

Comment: but not to be removed by the user, how can i do that?

Comment: You must change your ir.act.window and add a domain. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/fr/developer/reference/addons/actions.html#window-actions-ir-actions-act-window